# What is the auto-save path in BBEdit 14?

Tags: macos, bbedit

For BBEdit 14, what is the path where unsaved files are auto-saved (for re-opening when BBEdit is restarted)?

Many other[[1]](https://bbedit.narkive.com/p6HW1AbM/untitled-documents) internet[[2]](https://groups.google.com/g/textwrangler/c/9oSUCsf_o40) sources[[3]](https://github.com/drudge/bbedit-config/blob/master/Read%20Me.txt) point to the path being `~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Auto-Save Recovery`, however on multiple machines I use, my unsaved files still re-open despite the fact that the "Auto-Save Recovery" folder does not exist. I have even tried recursive-grep'ing my home directory for a unique string in one of my unsaved files, but I cannot find any match (grep never seems to complete, but that is a different issue).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BBEdit is fully sandboxed, so it's component folders are all inside the `Containers` subfolder of the Library.

```
~/Library/Containers/com.barebones.bbedit/Data/Library/BBEdit/Auto-Save Recovery
```

seems to 'contain' ;-) the auto-saves.

```
~/Library/Containers/com.barebones.bbedit/Data/Library/Application Support/BBEdit
```

also has most of the other stuff.

Comment: Many thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Others should note that `~/Library/Containers/com.barebones.bbedit/` might display as `~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/` within Finder.

Comment: Also note, if you got here looking to recover unsaved documents, the Rescued Documents folder contained those I accidentally deleted (they didn't show up in the Auto-Save Recovery folder.)

Comment: This answer (plus the comment) worked for me: ~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/Data/Library/BBEdit/Auto-Save Recovery

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone comes on this page after accidentally overwriting a remote file editing with BBEdit (such as I just did), you can recover almost any file from Documents > BBEdit Backups

I don't know if I'm just lucky or if it's the standard configuration, but in BBEdit Preferences > Text files, I have «Make backup before saving» and «Keep historical backups» options checked, which surely help in such a case.

Comment: Good tip. This deserves more props. I updated this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this question about where unsaved files located or about how to avoid re-opening unsaved files? For the first benwiggy has the answer.  For the latter - from [BBEdit 14 User Manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/BBSW-download/BBEdit_14.0.4_User_Manual.pdf):

> **Restore unsaved changes.** When this option is on, BBEdit will preserve the contents of any unsaved document contents when you quit (including untitled documents) and restore those documents the next time you launch it. If you prefer the traditional Quit behaviour, turn this option off

Manual states about deleting files in Auto-Save Recovery:

> **Auto-Save Recovery.** BBEdit will automatically create this folder. The Auto-Save Recovery folder contains information which BBEdit can use to recover the contents of unsaved documents after a crash, or to restore them at launch. Removing items from this folder can cause data loss

Comment: My original question was, indeed, about where unsaved files are located.
Thank you for the info, however!